# Unable to connect to Docker service

Tags: docker, docker-for-mac

I am running a Docker image in a MAC machine and when I logged into the container, I see the ip address as "172.17.0.2"( cat /etc/hosts).

1. How does docker choose the IP?
2. Is there any IP range that Docker choose?
3. What if I run multiple container on the same host? Will it be different?
4. /etc/resolve.conf gives some IP. What is that IP and where does it get?
5. How to connect to Docker service using the internal IP, say 172.17.0.2

> ping CONTAINER_ID  -> returns the IP 172.17.0.2

How does it resolve the hostname?

I tried reading through networking  but it doesn't help.

Also, I am running my service in the port 8443. Still, I am unable to connect.

I tried running,

> docker run -net host -p 8443:8443 IMAGE

Still no luck.

Tried the below approach also.

docker run -p MY_MACHINE_IP:8080:8080 IMAGE

Tried with,

> http://MY_MACHINE_IP:8080
>
> http://localhost:8080

None of the above works.

ifconfig output,

```
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=1203<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TXSTATUS,SW_TIMESTAMP>
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
XHC20: flags=0<> mtu 0
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 60:f8:1d:b2:cb:0c 
    inet6 fe80::49d:a511:dc4e:7960%en0 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0x5 
    inet 10.231.168.63 netmask 0xffe00000 broadcast 10.255.255.255
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
p2p0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 2304
    ether 02:f8:1d:b2:cb:0c 
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
awdl0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1484
    ether 0a:71:96:61:e4:eb 
    inet6 fe80::871:96ff:fe61:e4eb%awdl0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x7 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
en1: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=60<TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 72:00:07:57:48:30 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
en2: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=60<TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 72:00:07:57:48:31 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
bridge0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=63<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 72:00:07:57:48:30 
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x2
    member: en1 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 8 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en2 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 9 priority 0 path cost 0
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: <unknown type>
    status: inactive
utun0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 2000
    inet6 fe80::3f17:8946:c18d:5d25%utun0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xb 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
utun2: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1380
    inet6 fe80::20aa:76fd:d68:7fb2%utun2 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xd 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
utun3: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1380
    inet6 fe80::e42a:c616:4960:2c43%utun3 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x10 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
utun1: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1342
    inet 17...... --> 17.... netmask 0xff000000 
    inet6 fe80::93df:7780:862c:8a06%utun1 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x12 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
```

Answer (score 0):

for the first 4 question you can find [here](https://docs.docker.com/network/) some information, in general the `docker network` is the responsable about manager the network.

Usually I specify the prots like this:

`docker run -p 8443:8443 IMAGE`

and it work.

An reference to an existing topic is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18532364/9811690)

Comment: It works. I am able to connect using localhost:8443.  How can i connect using machine IP and How to connect using internal container ip?

Comment: If you can connect with localhost:8443, I think you can connect with IP_MACHINE:8443 too. The internal IP container is accessible only form the host where there is the container, usually it is use for communicate between the containers.

Comment: `--expose` have [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose) meaning, it does not publish the port.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** How does docker choose the IP?

When docker installed in your machine it will create `docker0` interface. It will gives ip address to your container whenever it launch.
you can verify the ip range for `docker0` by `ifconfig` command.

**2.** Is there any IP range that docker choose?

Yes, Please refer my answer 1.

**3.** What if i run multiple container on the same host? Will it be different?

Yes, It will be different from the range of `docker0` interface until you create your own network using `docker network create` for more refer : [Docker Networking](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/)

**4.**`/etc/resolve.conf` gives some IP. What is that IP and where does it get?

It's internal DNS of docker network you can give your DNS ip in `vi /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/docker.conf` add your DNS server on line like below:

```
[Service]
        ExecStart=
        ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2376 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock -g "/opt/docker_storage" --dns <replace-dns-ip>
```

**5.** How to connect to docker service using the internal IP, say `172.17.0.2`

You have to expose port to connect like `docker run -p 8443:8443 <image-name>`
after that you can connect by `telnet localhost 8443` or `curl http://172.17.0.2:8443`

**Most important**

Add the following to `/etc/sysctl.conf`

`net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1` and apply settings by

`sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf`

Hope this will help.

Thank you!

Comment: ifconfig docker0 -> ifconfig: interface docker0 does not exist. curl http : //172.17.0.2:8443  -> Failed to connect

Comment: just ifconfig do not include docker0

Comment: What is the use of --net host option?

Comment: Just ifconfig also doesnt list docker0. I am trying in MAC.

Comment: have you enabled ip forwarding

Comment: How to enable that?

Comment: mentioned in my answer under most important

Comment: share ifconfig output in your questions

Comment: sysctl: illegal option -- p for sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf

Comment: search for ip forwarding on MAC

Comment: Updated ifconfig output in the question.

Comment: are you using docker machine? just check ifconfig | grep 172.17.0.0

Comment: for ip forwarding in mac refer this https://serverfault.com/questions/97117/how-do-i-enable-ip-forwarding-in-macos-x

Answer (score 0):

Docker manages all of this internal networking machinery itself.  This includes allocating IP(v4) addresses from a private range, a NAT setup for outbound connections, and a DNS service to allow containers to communicate with each other.

A stable, reasonable setup is:

- Run `docker network create mynet`, once, to create a non-default network.  (Docker Compose will do this for you automatically.)
- Run your containers with `--net mynet`.
- When containers need to communicate with each other, they can use other containers' `--name` as DNS names (you can connect to `http://other-container-name`).
- If you need to reach a container from elsewhere, publish its service port using `docker run -p` or the Docker Compose `ports:` section.  It can be reached using the host's DNS name or IP address and the published port.
- Never ever use the container-private IP addresses (directly).
- Never use `localhost` unless you're absolutely sure about what it means.  (It's a correct way to reach a published port from a browser running on the host that's running the containers; it's almost definitely not what you mean from within a container.)

The problems I've seen with the container-private IP addresses tend to be around the *second* time you use them: because you relaunched the container and the IP address changed; because it worked from your local host and now you want to reach it from somewhere else.

To answer your initial questions briefly: (1-2) Docker assigns them itself from a network that can be configured but often defaults to 172.17.0.0/16; (3) different containers have different private IP addresses; (4-5) Docker provides its own DNS service and `/etc/resolv.conf` points there; (6) ICMP connectivity usually doesn't prove much and you don't need to `ping` containers (use `dig` or `nslookup` for DNS debugging, `curl` for actual HTTP requests).