# How to config docker's exposed port for an micro service app?

Tags: docker, go, microservices, go-micro

Excuse me.I've learned of go-micro and know micro service client has no need to  know which ip and port the micro service is deployed at.When a service runs itself, the port is randomly set, and the service is located by its service name,like `go.micro.api.user`.

The service side runs like:

```golang
     userService := micro.NewService(micro.Name("go.micro.api.user"))
     userService.Init()
     user.RegisterUserHandler(userService.Server(), new(User), api.WithEndpoint(&api.Endpoint{
          Name: "User.GetToken",
          Path: []string{"/user/token/"},
          Method: []string{"POST"},
          Handler: http.Handler,
     }),api.WithEndpoint(&api.Endpoint{
          Name: "User.GetUserName",
          Path: []string{"/user/username/"},
          Method: []string{"GET"},
          Handler: http.Handler,
     }))

    if er := userService.Run(); er != nil {
        panic(er)
    }
```

the client side like:

```golang
    service := micro.NewService(micro.Name("go.micro.api.user"))
    service.Init()

    // Create new greeter client
    userService := user.NewUserService("go.micro.api.user", service.Client())

    // Call the greeter
    rsp, err := userService.GetToken(context.TODO(), &user.Request{Username: "John", Password: "123"})
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    // Print response
    fmt.Println(rsp)
```

To deploy micro services in docker, I don't know how to config port in a docker container.

Comment: "When a service runs itself, the port is randomly set": Hmm? How do you run your service?

Comment: Is this helpful? https://dzone.com/articles/create-versatile-microservices-in-golang-part-2-do

Comment: @Henry as you see in the service. I don't specific the port,it will start at a random port and discovered by consul.

Comment: 3q，it helps a alot @AdamSmith

Answer (score 1):

You can set the port for go-micro servers using the `server_address` flag (see their [cli package](https://godoc.org/github.com/micro/cli)) or the `MICRO_SERVER_ADDRESS` env var (see [cmd doc](https://godoc.org/github.com/micro/go-micro/cmd)).

Once you do that, I suggest you experiment connecting to your service *without* Docker first. Once it all works, you can run it with Docker, [using the -p flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16958729/how-to-assign-as-static-port-to-a-container).